# Orders of Elements in GL(2,R)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let A =
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and B =
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

be elements in $GL(2, R)$. Show that $A$ and $B$ have finite orders but AB does not.

I know that $AB$ =
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and that $GL(2,R)$ is a group of 2x2 invertible matrices over $R$ with the matrix multiplication operation.

Firstly, I am confused as to how an element of this group can have an order. Is it that A and B are the products of invertible matrices in this group? Given that this is over $R$ the orders should be infinite. My book did not define the general linear group very well. Secondly, I would like some guidance on how to proceed following this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory))?

Comment: @JohnMa Yes. My book says that the order is the number of elements in the group.

Comment: First problem: your $AB$ is wrong.

Comment: Order of an element in a group is not the same thing as the order of a group. Yes, the order of the group is infinite. But the order of $A, B$ are not.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the matrix. I transcribed it incorrectly in mathjax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an order n means that n is the smallest positive number such that $A^n = I$. In this case, $I$ is of course the identity matrix.

$A^2$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1&0\\
0&-1\\
\end{pmatrix} = -I$

and so $A^4 = I$, order of A is 4

$B^3$=
$\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}^3=I$ so the order of B is 3

Given $AB$ =
$\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$, I'll let you check that $(AB)^n \neq I$ for any $n$ , thus proving $AB$ does not have finite order

Now to rigorously prove that $AB^n \neq I$ for any n, one way is to show that

$AB^n$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
1&-n\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

by induction.

Comment: Of course the matrix stated for $AB$ is not in $GL(2,\Bbb R)$ anyway (because the OP calculated it incorrectly).

Comment: haha I fixed it. Thanks for pointing that out I didn't even check the value of AB

Comment: Ok. So I manually did this A and B just for my reference. I got back to order 4 for A and order 3 for B like you said. I've done a few successive steps for AB and clearly I'm not going to get back to I. But I=is there a way to show generally that there exists no such $n$? So how do I know that it would't take say $n=100000$ for example? I suspect it would have to do with divisibility of the orders.

Comment: Oh wait never mind. This brings me back to AB. Ignore my question.

Comment: No it doesnt bring you back to AB. I edited my answer and added one more hint for proving that the order of AB is not finite

Comment: My mistake. I was looking A again. Ok so then by induction AB has infinite order. Thank You all so much.

Answer (score 1):

> The *order* of an element $g$ (in a group $G$) is the smallest
>   positive integer $n$ such that $g^n=e$, where $e$ is the identity of
>   the group. If such an $n$ exists, we say the the element $g$ has *finite order*.

With this in mind, you should look for some positives integers $n,m$ such that

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}^m=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

but, you must show that such integer does not exist for the product. This will be because, once you take successive powers, you reach a point where you get back to the beginning without reaching the identity. Try it by yourself!